# How to edit Vec3 x,y,z elements

Tags: visual-c++, vector

I have this variable

```
Vec3 PosData;
```

Which gets fed into this function

```
void Particles_Create(i32 iID, Vec3 &vecPos, i32 ProjectileType, i32 iNumberOfParticles, float fSpread, float fGrowSpeed, float fMaxSpeed, float fMaxSize, float fParticleTime);
```

it gets fed into like this

```
Vec3 PosData;
Particles_Create( 1, PosData, 1, 26, 4900, 0.005, 0.55, 0.5, 30);
```

And I want to be able to set the x,y and z elements.

if I define PosData as:

```
Vec3 PosData(float fvx,float fvy,float fvz);
Particles_Create( 1, PosData, 1, 26, 4900, 0.005, 0.55, 0.5, 30);
```

I would be able to set and change the x,y and z values but it cant be fed into the function above, so I need to keep it defined as 'Vec3 PosData;'

I've tried

```
Vec3 PosData;
Vec3 PosData.SetX = value;
Particles_Create( 1, PosData, 1, 26, 4900, 0.005, 0.55, 0.5, 30);
```

but I get a error at the line `Vec3 PosData.SetX = value;` saying

```
error c2659 '=' function as left operand
```

can someone tell me how to edit the xyz elements before its fed into the function

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the definition of your Vec3 class/struct so we can see how the SetX method works?  It doesn't seeem like you need the `Vec3` declaration again since `PosData` is declared the line above the error. Maybe something like this:

```
Vec3 PosData;    
PosData.SetX(value);// seems like a natural way to use the SetX method
```